# How do I make a cloth simulation animate on 2s(or 3s, and just simulations generally)

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, nla-editor

I have this cloth simulation and I want to animate it on 2s but there are no keyframes. I just want to use the NLA track and put a stepped modifier for the cloth simulation so I can animate it on 2s or 3s but I don't know how or if it's even possible.

Comment: You could convert it to shapekeys, if you look into the Cloth modifier, instead of Apply there's a Save as Shapekey, so you could create several shapekeys and keyframe them

Comment: I've considered that as a solution but it isn't really efficient

Comment: you can increase the speed of the simulation but I suppose that it's not what you want

Comment: Why do you need that? Isn't it like you should change file's frame rate to 12 (or 8 for 3s) instead? Thanks for more info.

Comment: @vklidu I have to save the output as images. I don't think it is possible or even effecient.

Comment: @moonboots it kinda works but it's a bit time consuming but not as much as shapekeys. I'll use it as a temporary solution until someone knows how to do it properly.

Comment: @SaiKei ??? it is even more unclear what is your goal now, sorry.

Comment: @vklidu my goal is to be able to hold frames like in 2d animation.

Comment: You need objects animate in 8fps style, but output render in higher fps (like 24fps), right? I'm asking because there is not direct way for cloth sim. And you are looking for workaround, so it is a good to know what are your limits. Cloth sim stores positions of each vertex per frame as a special set of data (not keyframes). In some cases I used Alembic format, but I'm not sure if there is something for you ...

Comment: @vklidu 12 fps actually. But it sucks there isn't much way to hold frames for the cloth simulation.

Comment: I'll just a wait a few more days to see if someone comes up with a better solution.